# How to store scientific large (microscopy) files?

Tags: python, bigdata, blob, storage, openstack

Here's the problem:

In a laboratory, very large microscopy data is created (from 1GB to 200GB per file).

We store the metadata as JSONS in MongoDB. But we can not find a suitable local / open source platform to store these files.
We have tried Hadoop but it is a very complex framework and we do not need many features. We only need a BLOB / Object Storage, if possible with a Python API to read and write data via a self-built GUI.

Have already evaluated Ceph, OpenStack Swift, OwnCloud, Gluster, etc., but we fail with each of them because of max_limit_size_of_file. Many of these mentioned have a max limit of 5GB per file.

What is the best way to store these files?
We need the following features:

- Python (and REST) API
- No Max-Limit size
- Open Source / Local Software
- Object / Blob Storage
- If possible replication of the data

Unfortunately, for compliance reasons, cloud solutions are not an option.

Answer (score 1):

For cases like these, sometimes the best thing to do is use the built in file-system to store your files.

Comment: can you describe what for advantages we gain if we store a 100gb czi file as a json?

Comment: Ahh, I missed that they were image files. You can store them as czi files themselves and use the python `czifile` package to read them.

Comment: the problem is here, how and where to store this large files

Comment: How - you will have to write your own custom implementation. I don't think there is a solution for this. 

Where - use your file system. For backup and replication you can setup a NAS

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [OMERO](https://www.openmicroscopy.org/omero/)? It sounds as if it covers most of your requirements. Although I dont know how far you can go with the Python API.

Comment: it seems interesting! which features or components of OMERO can be used as a storage?

Answer (score 0):

How many files do you need to keep? A plain file system with a file share works really well for storing large binary data. You can store your metadata in the mongoDB as well as the path to the directory.

One thing you might or might not need to worry about is how many files you need to store. In my experience if you're storing thousands of files then you need to work out how to distribute the files across the folders. If you store the hash of the object you can create a function that calculates what directory to store the file based on hash. If you're familiar with git, this is exactly how it stores objects.

Answer (score 0):

[vaex](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a library for loading in dataframes larger than the system memory allows, if you were to store your metadata with MongoDB and have a field for filename and you'd have your query abilities whilst keeping your data on the filesystem in a usable way